# Bazel project how to copy candidate directories during build stage

Tags: c++, bazel

I have a cpp project with the later file struct

MyProject

```
WORKSPACE

-directory_a
—mylib.cpp
—interface.h
—BUILD

-directory_b
—mylib.cpp
—interface.h
—BUILD

—directoryC
—main.cpp
—BUILD
```

In main.cpp , the I have a simple include code as

```
#include directory_real/interface.h
// do something
void main(){
 // say hello world
}
```

During building , I want to use genrule (or something like copy_directory) to rename my directory_b | directory_a into the ‘driectory_real’ based on some flags (In this case, try to move directory_b into directory_real).  The build file in the root I wrote is like the code next:

```
load("@bazel_skylib//rules:copy_directory.bzl", "copy_directory")
copy_directory("copy_directory_into_real","directory_b","directory_real")

cc_binary(
    name = "test",
    srcs = [
        "main.cpp",
    ],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    deps = [
        "//directory_real:mylib",
    ],
)
```

However, when `bazel build //directoryC:test`, the error occurs

ERROR: no such package 'directory_real': BUILD file not found in any of the following directories.

Anything wrong?

How can I wrote a correct bazel file to do this

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-skylib/blob/908bf1431d276245ba921e37862f74cec45ba9f4/tests/copy_directory/BUILD.bazel. You have to use the name of the `copy_directory()` target instead of the target directory name.

Comment: not works if I change my deps in main build file into “ copy_directory_into_real”